# Trying to pass in an array to my own method e.g my_inject that does the same thing as #inject

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to create a new method(e.g my_inject) that takes an array as an argument. This new method should replicate the same function of the inject method.

> Array.inject(1) { |product, n| product * n }

Inject method:

1. An accumulator starts at 0

2. my_inject iterates through the collection

3. Performs a calculation on each itereation

4. The accumulator then resets to the result of that
   calculation

5. Next iteration: while loop / recursion

***EDIT***: This could be a solution

```
  def my_inject(acc=0)
    array.each { |i| acc = yield(acc, i)}
    acc  
  end
end
```

Comment: I don;t undersand, wheither the `#my_inject` method shpould accept any argument? and why did you specify number `1` as na argument?

Comment: `inject` by definition takes a block and do sth completely different than what you are trying to do. I can understand that it is for exercise, but it seems like a very bad exercise.

Comment: updated the question with what i'm actually trying to do

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to write your own method that does the same thing as `#inject`? If so, what does the 'number to letter' problem have to do with that?

Comment: Yes. I was confused by hence the edit.

Comment: You do know that you do not have any Arrays in your example? (5..10) is a [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html), the inject method is taking two arguments, the seed value (1 a [Fixnum](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fixnum.html)) and the block of what to do as you iterate over the range, which is a [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Proc.html)

Comment: With your latest edit, `[5..10]` is an Array of a single element, the Range (5..10)... AND it fails to run in IRB due to a type error.

Comment: it's just to give an example of what i'm describing. edited.

Comment: How have you tried to write it? What have you run into? You know that `object.method` means invoking the method `method` on object, in which case object would be accessible through `self` within the body of `method` ?

Comment: I've new to programming and i've tried several different versions and not got very far. Write now i'm initalizing an accumulator object to start at 0. The Well-Grounded Rubyist is my guide : ). "invoking the method `method`" - no i didn't know that, but then i've been programming for less than 4 weeks. Thanks for tip. I'll attempt to incorporate `.self` in the body of the method. It would be helpful if you could answer the question with all the things you think i should know.

Comment: Okay, you're just trying to rewrite `#inject` as an exercise. I think that is clearer now. However, you've written your example as though `inject` is a class method instead of an instance method. It should be something like `my_array.my_inject`, (where `my_array` is an array like [5,1,8,3]), not `Array.inject`. Read up on the difference between class methods and instance methods.

Comment: Also, you don't 'pass' the array to `#inject` as an argument. You are calling the `#inject` method of the array object, as Charlie explained. I just feel you need to get a better feel for the basics before trying to solve a problem like this.

Comment: Maybe you need to go back to basics with a good tutorial. I can recommend the following two: 
http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/ and http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/ruby

Comment: @Kal perhaps i do. I've over complicated what i was trying to do. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: No worries. I'm only a part-time programmer myself, and I find it helpful to refresh on some of the basics from time to time, so there's no shame at all in starting one or both of those tutes from the beginning when you've only been programming such a short time. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inject method would look something like this:

```
def my_inject(my_array, accumulator)
  my_array.each do |item|
    accumulator = yield accumulator, item
  end
  accumulator 
end
```

This method iterates over the array, and for each item it passes the current accumulated value and the item itself to the given block. It takes the return value, and replaces the current accumulated value with it.

It returns the last result from the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the method directly on the array, here:

```
def my_inject(accumulator)
  self.each do |item|
    accumulator = yield accumulator, item
  end
  accumulator 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Having said what I said under a question - to redefine the method just open a class and define a method with the same name as the old one:

```
class Array
  def inject(value)       # You should never redefine method so it changes its interface/API!
    (64+value).chr
  end
end
```

ANSWER AFTER UPDATE

What you want is to define sum method on enumerable module:

```
module Enumerable
  def sum
    reduce(&:+)       
  end
end
```

If you are using rails it is already build in, so you can simply run `(5..10).sum`. Note that `(5..10)` is not an array but a Range, hence defining sum on Array won't work. However it makes sense to define it on Enumerable module (which define `reduce` and `inject` methods), which is included in both Array and Range (also in Hash and few other classes)

Comment: ruby only and i want to pass in an array to my method that does the same thing as inject